# Angular Material: Check if User clicked outside Datepicker without Making Any Selection

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular8

What's the Output Event to see if user clicked outside Material Angular datepicker?

1. Want to know specifically when user clicked on Datepicker,
2. Then Did not make any new selection, or did not reselect the date already entered
3. and clicked out? (hence closing it).

Closed Stream event is not the exact answer, since user could have clicked on date selection.

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: You could use `HostListener` to listen to `click` events and check if your element is part of `ClickEvent.target`.

Comment: hi @MikeS. yeah, I read about that, however heard HostListener can be major speed issue, company is kind of against using this, thanks

Comment: It's the angular way of listening to events and is definitely not a major speed issue, since it only listens to the events as long as the component is alive. But anyway - another way would be to add event callbacks to the native `onBlur` and `onFocus` events of your datepicker component.

Comment: hi @MikeS. can you write answer for onblur onfocus as a solution, can you provide simple code? and I can send points, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store in a variable

```
waitClose:boolean
```

Then, you can use the events (dateChange) to set the variable to false and (opened) to set the variable to true.

(closed)="waitClose && close()" make that the function close() only happens when you click outside

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
                            (dateChange)="waitClose=false" >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="waitClose && close()"
                            (opened)="waitClose=true">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8g2dk8?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Comment: hi @Elisio, posted another question here, maybe you know, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209606/javascript-zero-out-the-hour-minute-and-seconds-for-moment-variable